# Android app memory read

Tags: android, readprocessmemory

Normally, can access the computer executable program with ReadProcessMemory.

I am wondering if I can access the Android application with a readprocessmemory using a computer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
```

Check methods of this class. It should suit your needs.

E.g. to get used memory:

```
(runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory()) / 1048576L;
```